# How to use tumblr API in PHP?

Tags: php, html, tumblr

I am an infrequent user of PHP, but I need to connect to the tumblr api for a client to display their blog posts.

The api takes HTTP GET requests and returns JSON objects, neither of which do I know anything about. I have been trying to mess around with http_get on my localhost but it doesn't seem to be working at all. So my questions are thus:

1) What is the best method for performing an HTML GET in php?
2) Any info at all on using JSON objects, or even better directly related to the tumblr api. Some straight-up code would work wonders in helping me understand, but any advice is welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When I made my somewhat crufty [Tumblr backup script](https://github.com/treffynnon/Tumblr-Backup-PHP). I used [a PHP wrapper class](https://github.com/treffynnon/Tumblr-Backup-PHP/blob/master/libs/php-rest-api/class.tumblr.php) for the Tumblr API called [php-rest-api](http://code.google.com/p/php-rest-api/).

This way you can let the wrapping class deal with these aspects of the solution. You can see an example of using the class in my code in the [TumblrBackup.php file](https://github.com/treffynnon/Tumblr-Backup-PHP/blob/master/libs/TumblrBackup.php).